# Partial derivate in backpropagation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, machine-learning

I'm studying the backpropagation algorithm and in particular I'm studying its calculus from [3Blue1Brown's videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIeHLnjs5U8) on YouTube.
I understood the overall process, but there is a partial derivate that I cannot understand:
$$
  \frac{∂z^{(L)}}{∂w^{(L)}} = a^{(L-1)}
$$
Given:
$$
z^{(L)}=w^{(L)}a^{(L-1)}+b^{(L)}
$$

Why is the result simply $a^{(L-1)}$?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Because weights and biases are independent parameters therefore only the first term of $z^{(L)} = w^{(L)}a^{(L-1)} + b^{(L)}$ depends on $w^{(L)}$ and gives a non-zero derivative.

Comment: You can take a look here https://www.hashpi.com/backpropagation-equations for a full derivation of these equations.